# Oracle database configuration assistant hangs at cloning database (44%)

Tags: database, oracle

Oracle database configuration assistant hangs at cloning database (44%)

Could anyone help me out of this? i am stuck from last 4 hrs on same window.

DBCA log:

```
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [BasicStep.execute:269]  Executing Step : POST_DB_CREATION, Try count: 1
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [StepErrorHandler.setIgnorableErrors:267]  setting Ignorable Error: ORA-00439
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [StepErrorHandler.setIgnorableErrors:267]  setting Ignorable Error: ORA-00904
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [StepErrorHandler.setIgnorableErrors:267]  setting Ignorable Error: ORA-00942
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [StepErrorHandler.setIgnorableErrors:267]  setting Ignorable Error: ORA-00955
...
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=null
[AWT-EventQueue-0] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.278 IST ] [ProgressPane$RunNextStep.run:1347]  longTime 501137
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.341 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2084]  old Spool  = null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.341 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2085]  Setting Spool  = C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\postDBCreation.log
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.341 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2086]  Is spool appendable? --> true
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.341 IST ] [PostDBCreationStep.executeImpl:435]  Create/Update directory objects for OH and OB
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.372 IST ] [InstallUtils.getOracleBase:480]  OracleBase from orabase C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.372 IST ] [HADatabaseUtils.isGridMgmtDB:3236]  Mgmt DBName from srvm _mgmtdb
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.403 IST ] [BasicStep.execute:269]  Executing Step : UPDATE_NET_FILES, Try count: 1
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.403 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.403 IST ] [NetworkUpdateStep.executeImpl:187]  ADD TNSEntry..
...
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.403 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@10a88956
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [BasicStep.execute:269]  Executing Step : DIR_SERVICE, Try count: 1
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [DirServiceStep.executeImpl:182]  ds registration not selected or user trying to modify entry that does not exist.
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@10a88956
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [HADatabaseUtils.isGridMgmtDB:3236]  Mgmt DBName from srvm _mgmtdb
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:42.419 IST ] [PostDBCreationStep.executeImpl:612]  grant SYSDG, SYSBACKUP, SYSKM etc
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.043 IST ] [BasicStep.execute:269]  Executing Step : ACCOUNT_LOCK, Try count: 1
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.043 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.136 IST ] [SQLEngine.spoolOff:2160]  Setting spool off = C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\postDBCreation.log
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.136 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2084]  old Spool  = null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.136 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2085]  Setting Spool  = C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\lockAccount.log
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.136 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2086]  Is spool appendable? --> true
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [SQLEngine.spoolOff:2160]  Setting spool off = C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\lockAccount.log
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@10a88956
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2084]  old Spool  = null
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2085]  Setting Spool  = C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\postDBCreation.log
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [SQLEngine.setSpool:2086]  Is spool appendable? --> true
[Thread-65] [ 2019-07-10 15:41:43.168 IST ] [PostDBCreationStep.executeImpl:691]  executing datapatch C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\OPatch\datapatch.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Pritesh, what full version of Oracle on what platform?  If on Windows Is the user (you) a member of the OS group ora_dba?  If you have access to Oracle support see DBCA Create Of Database (Instance) Is Stuck At 77% (Doc ID 2403719.1).

Comment: Its Oracle 12c on Win7 64. I think I am not a member of that group.
Finally I had to cancel the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You really check the complete stack logs on C:\apps\oracle12cR2.1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\tcdb\

in order to check the Root Cause Error i can see datapatch is invoked when DBCA hangs.

regards.